# check the consultant_id of the current application user - ORACLE

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table with consultant_id, cst_name(consultant full name) and cst_start_date. I also have database users with the first names from cst_name.

I need to display the consultant_id of the current database application user by comparing the first name from cst_name to the current username.

The following code that I have tried returns no data.

```
SELECT consultant_id 
from lds_consultant 
WHERE  substr(cst_name, 1, instr(cst_name, ' ')) = ':app_user');
```

While the following code successfully returns only the first names from lds_consultant table.

```
SELECT substr(cst_name, 1, instr(cst_name, ' ')) "FIRST NAME" 
FROM lds_consultant;
```

Comment: You probably should not enclose the host variable `:app_user` in quotes.

Comment: Use: `= :app_user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [LIKE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm):

```
SELECT consultant_id
FROM lds_consultant
WHERE cst_name LIKE :app_user || ' %'
```

This way you get the rows where cst_name is composed by the name of the user, followed by a space and whatever else